# opening ngx-bootstrap typeahead on focus

Tags: javascript, ngx-bootstrap

Is there any way to open the ngx-typeahead when a user enters the input. In other words, on **`focus`**

[image]

I can get the dropdown to open if I type a single character into the input box, and then hit backspace.

[image]

Comment: why vote the question down? without even a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `[typeaheadMinLength]="0"` is the way to do this, but it also has the side effect of triggering a search even when nothing is typed in yet. I my case I needed to run the search on focus, but only if the textbox already had some content. I did this using a reference to the input's value:

```
<input #searchBox
[typeaheadMinLength]="searchBox.value?.length > 0 ? 0 : 1"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

just add this to the input

```
[typeaheadMinLength]="0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do two things to make this possible:

First, set [typeaheadMinLength]="0" to have the input open when nothing has been typed yet.

Secondly, since the type ahead input is the first field in the form, you may need to add a small delay by also setting [typeaheadWaitMs]="300 (or some value). This is because the input may receive focus before the values are available.

Example:

Comment: hi - this doesn't seem to do the trick, I have to type a character and then remove it still. I will debug the typeahead component and figure out if I can make it work.

Comment: Setting `typeaheadMinLength=0` solves my issue and setting `typeaheadWaitMs=100` solves the animation jitter.